# gevent-socketio how to originate messages from server

Tags: python, socket.io, gevent, gevent-socketio

This is my code:

```
class FirstNamespace(BaseNamespace):
    def on_some_event(self, msg):
        self.emit('ok '+msg)

@app.route('/socket.io/<path:remaining>')  # socket.io endpoint
def socketio_withpath(remaining):
    socketio_manage(request.environ,
                    {'/channel1': FirstNamespace}
    return 'ok'

@app.route('/dosomething/', methods=['POST'])  # simple http endpoint
def dosomething():
    data = request.form
    # ...
    # some code that triggers self.emit from within FirstNamespace 
    # ...
    return 'data processed'
```

I can happily send socket messages from frontend, they get processed and I receive replies from `on_some_event` method.

The problem is, I can only receive a message if I first send one myself.

But how can I start receiving messages without being the first one to talk?

For example, if someone sends a POST to the `/dosomething/` endpoint, how can it trigger an `emit` to my client websocket?

--

I can do this in `flask-socketio` but it does too much magic to my taste. Is there a lower level implementation for this?

Comment: don't understand the question. You can send any time messages with `self.emit('response_channel', msg)`.

Comment: @Daniel yeah, but imagine you have another endpoint, for example `localhost:8080/dosomething`. Suppose you want to issue a regular POST there and you want it to trigger an `emit` to a websocket. How do you go about that?

Comment: please edit your question, to make clear, what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to collect all channel1-Connections in a set, then you can send messages to all connections:

```
from weakref import WeakSet

class FirstNamespace(BaseNamespace):
    connections = WeakSet()

    def initialize(self):
        self.connections.add(self)

    def on_some_event(self, msg):
        self.emit('ok '+msg)

@app.route('/socket.io/<path:remaining>')  # socket.io endpoint
def socketio_withpath(remaining):
    socketio_manage(request.environ,
                    {'/channel1': FirstNamespace}
    return 'ok'

@app.route('/dosomething/', methods=['POST'])  # simple http endpoint
def dosomething():
    data = request.form
    for conn in FirstNamespace.connections:
        conn.emit("response_channel", data)
    return 'data processed'
```